# Add program to PATH

Tags: 12.04, command-line

A new Question today :).

I've downloaded Sublime Text 2 for Linux (x32).
Now I want to add it to the PATH-Variable.
How does this work?

Greets,

Baldoius

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add only a directory path to `path variable`.Run the below commands on terminal to add a directory path to the `PATH-Variable`,

```
su root
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/directory
```

To add the path permanently, add the following line at the end of `~/.bashrc`file

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the below line at the end,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/directory
```